# SQL server 2008 Stored procedure syntax issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

This is my first stored procedure and i would really appreciate some help crafting it :)

I have had a go but im getting the following error which appears wherever P.RL is. I tried renaming P.RL to Products.RL with the same result.

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure UpdateInventoryForSCRAPorder, Line 19
The multi-part identifier "Products.HD" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure UpdateInventoryForSCRAPorder, Line 19
The multi-part identifier "Q.QuantityOrdered" could not be bound.
```

Perhaps theres a more efficient way of doing what im trying, or maybe just a syntax tweak is needed.

The purpose of this Stored Proc is to update the inventory levels in a products table. There are two columns that hold the inventory figures. One column (RL) contains quantities of stock that have passed quality checks and are released (hence the RL) for ordering.

The other column (HD) is for stock that is held for various reasons, but it has been decided that they can be included in orders.

So what im trying to do here is ensure that the inventory is updated as soon as a product is ordered. The if statements are trying to cover all scenarios where for example some released product is ordered as well as some that is held.

So for example and order for 10 items: If there are 4 items in the RL column, add these first to the order and take the remainder from the held column.

All help is appreciated !

here is the stored proc

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateInventoryForSCRAPorder

@OrderID Int,
@LocalAmount Int

AS
BEGIN

    IF (Products.RL > 0 and Products.HD > 0) and (Q.QuantityOrdered > Products.RL)
      Begin
    
        set @LocalAmount = Q.QuantityOrdered - RL
    
        UPDATE P
        Set RL = 0,
            HD = HD - @LocalAmount,
            P.OutstandingOrders = P.OutstandingOrders + Q.QuantityOrdered
        From
            Products P  join    
            (Select ProductID, sum(Quantity) as QuantityOrdered from OrderDetails where OrderID = @OrderId Group By ProductId)  Q 
            on P.ID = Q.ProductID
      END

    ELSE IF (P.RL > 0 and P.HD > 0) and (Q.QuantityOrdered < P.RL)
        Begin
          UPDATE P
            Set RL = RL - Q.QuantityOrdered, 
            P.OutstandingOrders = P.OutstandingOrders + Q.QuantityOrdered
                From
                    Products P  join    
                    (Select ProductID, sum(Quantity) as QuantityOrdered from OrderDetails where OrderID = @OrderId Group By ProductId)  Q 
                    on P.ID = Q.ProductID
        END 
    ELSE IF (P.RL = 0 and P.HD > 0) 
        Begin
          UPDATE P
            Set HD = HD - Q.QuantityOrdered, 
            P.OutstandingOrders = P.OutstandingOrders + Q.QuantityOrdered
                From
                    Products P  join    
                    (Select ProductID, sum(Quantity) as QuantityOrdered from OrderDetails where OrderID = @OrderId Group By ProductId)  Q 
                    on P.ID = Q.ProductID
        END 
    ELSE IF (P.RL > 0 and P.HD = 0) 
        Begin
          UPDATE P
            Set RL = RL - Q.QuantityOrdered, 
            P.OutstandingOrders = P.OutstandingOrders + Q.QuantityOrdered
                From
                    Products P  join    
                    (Select ProductID, sum(Quantity) as QuantityOrdered from OrderDetails where OrderID = @OrderId Group By ProductId)  Q 
                    on P.ID = Q.ProductID
        END         

END
```

---

#### Solved

After a good nights sleep and lots of caffeine, I tried a different approach and asked a different question.

Credit to Devart for the last piece of this puzzle. See [Single update statement method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34946367/sql-server-join-issue)

Apparently my requirement boils down to this:

```
UPDATE Products
SET HD = HD + RL,
    RL = 0
FROM P
WHERE RL < 0
    AND ID IN (
            SELECT ProductID
            FROM dbo.OrderDetails
            WHERE OrderID = @OrderId
        )
```

Comment: `IF (Products.RL > 0 and Products.HD > 0)` where is `SELECT`?

Comment: hi, im trying to update the table values, not select records. cheers

Comment: `SQL stored procedure` is not OO world like JAVA/C#. You cannot refer as `table_name.column_name` without any other clause.

Comment: Yes im trying to learn. How would i go about getting this to work please? I got the initial syntax from MSDN documentation but can't get it to work.

Comment: Was your question solved by an answer here then please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/273645) or if it wasn't from an answer, please provide an answer yourself and accept that. Do not simply edit the title to start it with `SOLVED`. That is just silly...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do, although it looks more complicated than necessary.  However, you have a syntax error on the very first line in the body:

```
IF (Products.RL > 0 and Products.HD > 0) and (Q.QuantityOrdered > Products.RL)
```

What is `Products`?  What is `Q`?  Qualified column names belong in a SQL statement (`SELECT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE`), not in control flow.

I'm not sure how to fix the logic.  Putting the conditions in a `WHERE` clause might be the right solution.

Comment: Thanks for that. What im trying to do is, for a given order, say it contains four items in the orderdetails table, for each of those items, i want to find that product in the product table, and subtract the quantity ordered. The quantity available to order is split into two columns, so i need to first subtract from the RL column, and if there is a remainder, take it from the HD column. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `table_name.column_name` directly in if statement, you can use `select` for condition. For example:

```
If ( Select sum(RL) as RL from Product Group By ID)>0
begin
--put here your statement

end
```

or you can put to variable:

```
declare @SumRL int
set @SumRL = (Select sum(RL) as RL from Product Group By ID)
if (@SumRL>0)
begin
--put here your statement
end
```

I don't really know what you are trying to do. I don't know structur table you use, but I hope my answer can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateInventoryForSCRAPorder
(
    @OrderID INT,
    @LocalAmount INT
)
AS BEGIN

    UPDATE P
    SET RL -= CASE
                    WHEN (P.RL > 0 AND P.HD = 0) OR (P.RL > 0 AND P.HD > 0 AND Q.QuantityOrdered < P.RL)
                        THEN Q.QuantityOrdered
                    WHEN (P.RL > 0 AND P.HD > 0 AND Q.QuantityOrdered > P.RL)
                        THEN RL    
                    ELSE 0 END,
        HD -= CASE 
                    WHEN P.RL = 0 AND P.HD > 0
                        THEN Q.QuantityOrdered
                    WHEN (P.RL > 0 AND P.HD > 0 AND Q.QuantityOrdered > P.RL)
                        THEN @LocalAmount
                    ELSE 0
                END
        OutstandingOrders += Q.QuantityOrdered
    FROM Products P
    JOIN (
        SELECT ProductID,
                SUM(Quantity) AS QuantityOrdered
        FROM OrderDetails
        WHERE OrderID = @OrderID
        GROUP BY ProductId
    ) Q ON P.id = Q.ProductID
    WHERE (P.RL > 0 AND P.HD = 0)
        OR (P.RL = 0 AND P.HD > 0)
        OR (P.RL > 0 AND P.HD > 0 AND Q.QuantityOrdered < P.RL)
        OR (P.RL > 0 and P.HD > 0 AND Q.QuantityOrdered > P.RL)

END
```