# SQL server join issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

i have the following statement in a stored procedure that is returning strange results. Given two columns where one (RL) is less than 0 e.g -2, it should add 2 to another column (HD). If the negative value was -8 it should add 8 to the HD column.

In a test ive just done, the RL column had 0 and HD was 2. I changed the RL to -2 and run the code. I was **EXPECTING** : RL = 0 and HD = 4. INSTEAD the **RESULT** was RL = 0 and HD = 5.

I think the problem is due to the presence of the join. How would i write this to replace the join with a WHERE clause please.

```
UPDATE P
SET P.HD = P.HD + P.RL
    ,P.RL = 0
FROM Products P
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id
        ,RL
    FROM Products
    WHERE id IN (
            SELECT ProductID
            FROM OrderDetails
            WHERE OrderID = @OrderId
            )
        AND RL < 0
    ) Q ON P.ID = Q.id
```

cheers

Comment: Don't add "solved" to the question title. StackOverflow already knows if a question is solved if you accept an answer.

Comment: Hi, ok sorry was unaware of that. I was thinking i don't want to waste other users time looking at a question that has already been answered. So once an answer is accepted im guessing the question "disappears" ?

Comment: It depends of how you search, for example it will not appear in the unawnsered questions tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

```
UPDATE Products
SET HD = HD + RL,
    RL = 0
FROM P
WHERE RL < 0
    AND ID IN (
            SELECT ProductID
            FROM dbo.OrderDetails
            WHERE OrderID = @OrderId
        )
```

Small check -

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (a INT, b INT)

INSERT INTO @t (a, b)
VALUES (1, 2)

UPDATE @t
SET a = b, b = 0

SELECT * FROM @t
```

Comment: Genius ! :) Thank you Devart. That worked. So why does using a join make it look like its running the calculation more than once? Am new to this and still learning SQL

Comment: I will be honest... don't know ;) you does not provide any `DDL` and data sample, so i just provide a syntactically correct answer without any re-read...

Comment: For learning purposes just check this book :) http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Server-Fundamentals-Developer-Reference/dp/0735658145/ref=asap_bc?ie=UTF8

Comment: Thanks for the link. While im there ill also find out what a DDL is ! :)